# Access classes with prototyping

Tags: javascript

I have a prototype class, and from this I initialize other classes:

```
this.classA = new lp.ClassA();
this.classB = new lp.ClassB();
```

I was just wondering, is there a way to access class A methods inside class B (and the other way round too), how can I reference it?

Comment: Nope. Each var gets assigned a new instance

Comment: Those `ClassA` and `ClassB` constructors don't return new *classes*, but create *instances*, don't they?!

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you pass the instance to the B constructor. Or you are using some kind of closure like RequireJS where you can pass it.

```
this.classA = new lp.ClassA();
this.classB = new lp.ClassB(this.classA);
```